# mysql switch to alternative table depending on conditions

Tags: php, mysql

this post is a long one sorry for that but the problem is complex too.

Using mysql and php,
I can solve my problem with 3 sql requests, but not in 1, nor in 2.

So that's why I post here :
does any of you know a way to do it in less than 3 strokes ?

(sorry for my english)

First let me explain the context :
it's about theme park !

So there is the theme park owner,
and he owns a theme park with different zones, and each zone contains games.
Each game can be setup with different settings, according to a game manager (the human responsible for the game).

Here is what the interesting part of the schema looks like
there are 5 tables

themeparkzone
--name (varchar)

themeparkzone_has_game_with_manager
--themeparkzone_id (pk)
--game_id (pk)
--manager_id (fk)
--game_settings (text)

themeparkzone_has_game
--themeparkzone_id (pk)
--game_id (pk)
--game_settings (text)

game
--name (varchar)

manager
--name (varchar)

Two tables may need more explanations :

themeparkzone_has_game_with_manager and themeparkzone_has_game.

themeparkzone_has_game may hold the default settings for the games, if the themepark owner
wrote them.

Then themeparkzone_has_game_with_manager holds the game settings that the game_manager has (or has not) setup,
and those settings should override the default settings from the themeparkzone_has_game table when set up.

Because the themepark owner wants his themepark to be very attractive, he plans to change the settings every day,
and here is the convention that he and his team will have to deal with :

to decide which game settings will apply,

we have the following vars are given at startup :
  - the manager_id : for example 22.
  - the themeparkzone ids for today, for example 12,13,14

So the final goal is :
for the given manager_id, and for the given themeparkzone_ids,
find out the name and settings of the games,

given that :
if a setting is set in the themeparkzone_has_game_with_manager it will apply
else
if a setting is set in the themeparkzone_has_game it will apply
else
there is no game.

That's the problem I have,
and because I could'nt do it within 1 request,
I spent a first request to loop the themeparkzone_ids,
so that the problem now is to find the game name and settings for a given manager_id and a given themeparkzone_id.

At this point, I can do it in two requests, but I wondered if one can do it in one.

My requests are :

SELECT g.name,w.game_settings
  FROM game g
  INNER JOIN themeparkzone_has_game_with_manager w on w.game_id=g.id
  WHERE w.manager_id=22
  AND w.themeparkzone_id in(12,13,14)

and

SELECT g.name,h.game_settings
  FROM game g
  INNER JOIN themeparkzone_has_game h on h.game_id=g.id
  WHERE h.themeparkzone_id in(12,13,14)

Foreach of them, I put the resulting array in a php array and then mix them
according to the conventions.

So I was wondering if there was one way to solve the conditions in a mysql request
instead of doing it with php.

A request that would do something like this :
foreach (themeparkzone_id and manager_id)
if exists a matching setting in themeparkzone_has_game_with_manager
takeit,
else
if exists a matching setting in themeparkzone_has_game
takeit,
else
takenothing.

Hope someone understood what I tried to explain.

Comment: Is there a really compelling reason to do this in mySQL instead of PHP, where it already works? Do you have any performance issues? I find it hard to imagine this is worth the effort trying to get into mySQL - making it a query condition whether a table exists or not doesn't feel in sync with the spirit of mySQL to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your database layout, I think it might be better to change some things.

I would put `themeparkzone_has_game_with_manager` and `themeparkzone_has_game_with_manager` in one single table. Then I would create a new table `games_managers` that establishes a connection of which managers can manage which games.

Then I think, it should be possible to do it with fewer requests.

Note that you have to work out the details for yourself, i.e. you might specify a flag for each game if it needs to have a manager or not, etc.

Comment: I agree with this (though I think you meant to reference different table names so you may want to edit your answer a bit). Have one table, with an extra boolean field specifying whether this was set by a manager or not.

Comment: @Nick If we set boolean field that this is specified by manager , then the default setting for that game will be lost..

Comment: Yes, If I change the structure like you said,
the default settings are lost and that's the problem !
How to fetch in one request a table that may contains overriding settings, but if no record is found try to get settings from the default settings table
?

Comment: Not if you have two rows - one for the default setting, and another for the manager-set setting. Fetch any rows matching a particular theme park zone - use the manager-set one if it is found, otherwise use the default. You probably don't even need a boolean flag - just assume if manager_id is null then it's not manager-set.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE`.

```
SELECT
    g.name,
    COALESCE(w.game_settings, h.game_settings)
FROM
    game AS g
    INNER JOIN themeparkzone_has_game AS h ON h.game_id = g.id
    LEFT JOIN themeparkzone_has_game_with_manager AS w ON
        w.game_id = g.id AND
        w.themeparkzone_id = h.themeparkzone_id AND
        w.manager_id = 22
WHERE
    h.themeparkzone_id IN (12, 13, 14)
```

Unlike an `INNER JOIN`, a `LEFT JOIN` always contains at least one row for each row in the left-hand table, even if there are no rows in the right-hand table matching the join conditions. In this case the columns from the right-hand table will all be `NULL`. `COALESCE()` returns the first non-`NULL` value it is supplied with, so if there are no matching rows in `themeparkzone_has_game_with_manager`, it will return the `game_settings` value from `themeparkzone_has_game`.

Comment: It didn't work as expected (got an empty result),
but I'm going to workaround with these inner join, left join and coalesce things, it sounds good. thanx.

Answer (score 0):

hooray,
I finally found a turn around,
it's a little messy for a newbie like me but it works, and …
only the results matter…

Here is the request that corresponds to my needs :
thanx all for your help :

> SELECT
>       coalesce(g.name,g2.name),
>       coalesce(w.params, h.params)
>   FROM
>       themeparkzone z
>   LEFT JOIN themeparkzone_has_game_with_manager w ON w.themeparkzone_id=z.id AND w.manager_id=2
>   LEFT JOIN themeparkzone_has_game h on h.themeparkzone_id=z.id
>   LEFT JOIN game g ON g.id=w.game_id
>   LEFT JOIN game g2 ON g2.id=h.game_id
>   WHERE z.id in(12,13,14)

So this request fetch result in the themeparkzone_has_game_with_manager table,
and if not founded, try to fetch result from the themeparkzone_has_game
and if not founded either, still return a null result.
Hope it helps someone.